# where are images stored inside programs?

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, firefox

i'm new to programs so bear with me

For example, Firefox.. I go to the C/program files/mozilla/firefox folder ..but I don't see the images/buttons they used for the default theme of the program

Also, photoshop and other programs: how are the buttons, images, and other media stored (not in a folder from what I see)?

same thing when I made a simple program in visual c++, i don't see where the icon is located at?

thanksvery much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images are usually stored as resources in DLL or EXE files.
You can see the resources by opening a compiled binary in Visual Studio.

Firefox stores images in JAR files for skins.

Comment: So, can hundreds of images and other files be stored inside one .exe file for a program? are they compiled or how does that go about?

Comment: Yes.  You can add them as resources.

Answer (score 3):

In the resource section of the executable file. This section of file acts as an embedded storage location which is indexed by the resource table.

You can use a program such as [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to browse or even change native embedded resources.